# Ratio vs. Difference

Tags: operations-research

The naturals: $\{1, 2, 3, ... \}$

$2 - 1 = 1$ and $\frac{2}{1} = 2$

$3 - 2 = 1$ and $\frac{3}{2} = 1.5$

$4 - 3 = 1$ and $\frac{4}{3} = 1.333...$

.
.
.
$167834632 - 167834631 = 1$ and $\frac{167834632}{167834631} = 1.000000006...$

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (n + 1) - n = 1$

But ...

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n + 1}{n} = 1$

We've only considered a difference of $1$ (consecutive numbers) but look at the following example:

$10000001000 - 10000000000 = 1000$

$\frac{10000001000}{10000000000} = 1.0000001$

**Observation**
*Ratio* fails to distinguish or is bad at distinguishing one very large number from another very large number, but *Difference* can.
*Ratios* create an *illusion* of *equality*, but *differences* expose the *druj* (deception).

**Question**
Is this a known mathematical fact? What are views/opinions of mathematicians on the matter?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what kind of answer you're looking for. I think it's rather intuitive that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+C}{n} = 1 \qquad \text{for any constant }C
$$
and it's definitely a "known thing", as far as I'm considered.

Comment: **Mathematical Illusions** vis-à-vis *ratios*.

Answer (score 2):

Ratios and differences have different meanings and measure different things. Your assertion that differences are *superior* because they are intuitively better in **one** application is very short sighted.

For example, the distance between the Moon and the Earth is about $400{,}000$ kilometers. Now, you tell me, which of these two sentences conveys information better?

1. The sun is about $4000$ times farther from the Earth than the Moon
2. The sun is about $150$ million kilometers farther from the Earth than the Moon.

Comment: I don't know. There's our brain, our senses, biology. Are human beings better at discerning *scaling* (multiplication) or *addition/subtraction*?

Answer (score 1):

*Illusion?* *Deception?*

The ratio and the difference constitute distinct ways to think about or compare pairs of numbers. Either might be more informative—or appealing—depending on context and what features of the comparison are of interest.

Consider the old joke about the museum guard who told a visitor, “This fossil skeleton is sixty-six million twenty-one years old.” The visitor responded, “Wow! How do we know that?” to which the guard replied, “When I started here I was told it was sixty-six million years old, and I have been here twenty-one years.”

Comment: Si, but $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x + C}{x} = 1$. What is $1$? That, mon ami, is the question.

Comment: If that were indeed the question, then you should have simply asked that in the OP.  What is it that you sincerely wish to know?

Comment: The *multiplicative identity* ($1$) corresponds to the *additive identity* ($0$). $a - a = 0 \implies \frac{a}{a} = 1$ and vice versa

Comment: Ok, @AgentSmith, and that’s why they’re both called the same thing, *identities*. But my query remains, What is it that you sincerely wish to know?